# Make automatic run without command button VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hi guys i'm try learn VBA Excel , i have a problem in my project

[image: See this picture]

i'm try to make a insert statement , when i'm insert "1" then the result is "book 1",
but to show the result i need click some command button, 
so how can i do to make it automatic to show the result without click button

This is before i click the command button
[image: this is the before i click the command button]

This is after i click the command button
[image: this is after i click the command button]

thanks guys , sory for my bad english :D

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your code as text, not as a screenshot, thanks.

Comment: Also, take a look at the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event for this to happen automatically.

Comment: agree with @BigBen. `Worksheet_Change` can handle that for you.. You may also want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)